# ReactJS How to handover and add a input with usestate

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to read a number from a input field with useState. This number
should be added or subtracted to the previous number and then the
result should appear after a click on the button in a diffrent field.
This is my code:

```
function App() { 
  const [überstunden, setNewÜberstunden] = useState(0.0);  
  function addÜberstunden() {
    setNewÜberstunden([prevState => prevState + überstunden])
  }  
  function decrementÜberstunden(){
      setNewÜberstunden([prevState => prevState - überstunden])
  } 
  return (<div className="Box1"> 
        <h2>Überstunden</h2>
        <input 
            type="number" 
            placeholder="Überstunden"
            style={{ width: "98%", marginRight: "10px" }}  
            onChange={() => setNewÜberstunden(überstunden)} />
        <p></p>
        <button onClick={addÜberstunden}>Hinzufügen</button>
        <button onClick={decrementÜberstunden}>Nehmen</button>
        <p>Aktuelle Überstunden: {überstunden} </p> 
   </div> ); 
}
```

[Here is a image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBmf9.png)

I hope you understand my question and I would appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are many ways to solve this riddle.

Considering you seem to want to use `useState` hook, you can use another state variable to keep the total value (`[total, setTotal]`). The main reason you can't reuse the same state variable to both use it for the `input` field and then for totals as well is because React input field is controlled (by react). You could also use a non-controlled approach. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Below is a working example (I added english variables):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [überstunden, setNewÜberstunden] = useState(0);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

  function addÜberstunden() {
    setTotal((prevState) => prevState + überstunden);
  }
  function decrementÜberstunden() {
    setTotal((prevState) => prevState - überstunden);
  }
  return (
    <div className="Box1">
      {" "}
      <h2>Überstunden</h2>{" "}
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Überstunden"
        style={{ width: "98%", marginRight: "10px" }}
        value={überstunden}
        onChange={(e) => setNewÜberstunden(Number(e.target.value))}
      />{" "}
      <p></p> <button onClick={addÜberstunden}>Hinzufügen</button>{" "}
      <button onClick={decrementÜberstunden}>Nehmen</button>{" "}
      <p>Aktuelle Überstunden: {total} </p>{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also, trying to save an array here, most likely won't take you far so I removed the array from those parameters.

`setTotal([(prevState) => prevState + überstunden]);`

Here's a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-fast-z37tb?file=/src/App.js) to see it working.